# How am I messing up my HttpGet parameter encoding?

Tags: java, uri, http-get, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have this URL (which executes in a browser fine):

https://api-test.company.com/contacts/?q=email=jlowder@company.com

which I am trying to use HttpClient to execute.  I've tried:

```
    String URL = "https://api-test.company.com/contacts?q=" + URLEncoder.encode("email=jlowder@company.com");
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet c = new HttpGet(URL);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(c);
    String resultContent = myRestCall.GetResponseText(response);
```

This returns the error:

QUERY_PARAMunable to parse query string 'email=jlowder@company.com'

And I've tried:

```
    GetMethod method = new GetMethod("https://api-test.company.com/contacts/?q=");
    method.setQueryString(new NameValuePair[] {new NameValuePair("email", "jlowder@company.com")});
    HttpGet c = new HttpGet(method.toString());
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(c);
```

Which returns:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.

So how exactly do I correctly parse this simple GET request?

Thanks.

Comment: Correctly who is said that correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.  I'm asking how to properly execute my GET request with the given parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you still have an parameter q which should be passed, too. Normaly, you have key/values. Why do you have such a constellation?

?q=email=jlowder@company.com

There is a value for "q" missing. Or do you want to set "email=jlowder@company.com" as value for "q" Then you should escape the "="

Comment: That appeared to be the problem.  I needed to include the q= into the parameter.  Of course the return value is now different from what I get when executing in a webpage, but that's something else..